# list wordpress posts from current category only

Tags: wordpress, get, posts

I'm attempting to create a second nav menu on my wordpress site.

I want this to show links to all posts within the current category only.

I've been experimenting with the get_posts function but am struggling to find how to dynamically select the current category. i.e.  what to place in here **category=x**

Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is my template code I have been using

```
<ul id="catnav">

     <?php
     global $post;
     $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category=1');
     foreach($myposts as $post) :
     ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>



    </ul>
```

Comment: I think I have this code at home. I will share it if you remind me by answering on this comment. Will check if I got it on my inbox too.

Comment: Thanks Pablo, if you could it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Finally solved it with this code from here: http://www.snilesh.com/resources/wordpress/wordpress-recent-posts-from-current-same-category/

Modified it to include current page and list ascending

```
<ul id="catnav">
<?php
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post_status'=>'publish', 'order'=>'ASC' ));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<li><a href="?p=46">Why Us?</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<!--Insted Of this-->
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category=1');
<!--Use This-->
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
query_posts('cat='.$cat_ID.'&showposts=5&order=ASC');
```

Comment: Thanks Balu, but this didn't seem to work. What do you propose to do with `code` foreach($myposts as $post) :

Answer (score 2):

```
$args=array(
'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page'=>-1,
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

So I found this bit of code which works great in showing all posts in the current category.

```
 <ul id="catnav">

 <?php
foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category ) {
$the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $category->category_nicename . '&showposts=5&order=ASC');
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
}
?>


</ul>
```

But I have several categories I wish to exclude. 
Some posts exist in two categories I want to exclude showing the post in categories 8,9 and 11.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to get posts from category id instead of category name
so that you can write an if else condition and you can exclude the posts which are having the id as 8,9,11